# SQL query to order on two related datetime columns

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Server table with two columns, startDate and endDate.  I need a query that returns the rows such that the startDate of the next row matches the endDate of the current row.  For example
startDate - endDate
2011/01/01 - 2011/01/02
 
2011/01/02 - 2011/01/05
2011/01/05 - 2011/01/13
2011/01/13 - 2011/01/15
... if there is no start matching previous end   then just grab next startDate...
2011/01/19 - 2011/01/23
2011/01/23 - 2011/01/25

Comment: Seems like you only need to sort by startdate ascending

Comment: are there other overlapping dates? can't you just sort on the startDate?

Comment: @Richard Most definitely not, what about case when there are holes between dates? From given sample dates are follow-ups. OP should clarify.

Comment: OP says "... then grab next startDate", so we don't care about holes, so why not just sort by startDate?

Comment: Could you clarify your problem statement and define your desired results set? As it is now, it's unclear exactly what you want returned.

Answer (score 2):

select t1.StartDate, t1.EndDate 
from Dates t1
inner join Dates t2 on t1.EndDate=t2.StartDate